# Finding a string on a javascript based website and innitiate click

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to find a picture on a javascript based website and click on it. Below you can see the code I have tried, but always getting error, the website can only be opened via Internet Explorer, no other browser will display it properly. What should I change or how should I approach that clicking on the button would open the website, find the picture and initiate a click on it?

```
        var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
        options.AddAdditionalCapability("IsJavaScriptEnabled", true);
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver");
        IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        //IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver("phantomjs Folder Path", options);
        //IWebDriver driver = ($"c:\\Users\\kocsism\\Documents\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\", options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");

        try
        {
            string pagesource = driver.PageSource;
            //driver.FindElement(By.Id("New Incident..."));
            //driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("New Incident..."));
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("new_incident_16.png"));
            Console.Write("your element has been found");
        }
        catch (Exception some_exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(some_exception.Message);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

This code runs on a button click, and while trying I\'m getting the following error: "phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error". Also as additional here is the sample code behind the javascript file.

"ahdtop.c_new('cr',0,'','','PRESET=type:I')", 1, 0, 0, "I", "", 
_parentId, "/Something/img/incident_10.png", "create a new incident");

How can I do that when click on the button it is opening the website finding this picture and innitiatin a click on it using the installed ie browser maybe if no other way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is finding the element you are looking for? 
By.Name("new_incident_16.png") would be looking for a tag like:

```
<img name="new_incident_16.png"/>
```

Just wanted to confirm as "new_incident_16.png" seems like it would be the src, not the name.

If it is finding the element, then you should be able to click it using one of the following methods:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.Name("new_incident_16.png"));
button.Click();
```

If for some reason that does not work, you can click the button through javascript with the following:

```
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.Name("new_incident_16.png"));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```